# Ext Gwt Web desktop shortcut

Tags: java, gwt, extjs

Simple question, I'm novice at Ext Gwt library, and trying to set up web desktop sample app, included on the extgwt distibution.
Everything is ok, but I can't see desktop shortcuts, on the sample example from ext site, all is ok.
My code:

```
Shortcut s1 = new Shortcut();
s1.setText("My shortcut");
s1.setId("grid-win-shortcut");
s1.setData("window", gridWindow);
s1.addSelectionListener(shortcutListener);
desktop.addShortcut(s1);
```

css:
    #grid-win-shortcut img {
         width: 48px; height: 48px; background: url(../icons/grid48x48.png);
    }
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

**UPDATED:**
I'm found it!
Just add:

```
<div id="x-desktop">
   <dl id="x-shortcuts"></dl>
</div>
```

inside the body tag. That's all.